# Why isn't my accessor being included in toJson()?

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-4

I have a model `Contract` that has an accessor for the `projects` attribute. The attribute is an associative array of "id" => array, but the accessor transforms the array into a collection of `Project` models:

```
public function getProjectsAttribute($val)
{
    $projects = array();

    foreach($val as $projId => $projData)
    {
        $proj = new Project($this->roundingPrecision, $projData);
        $proj->_id = $projId;
        $projects[] = $proj;
    }

    return Collection::make($projects);
}
```

If I get a `Contract` object, I can call `$contract->projects` and it works as expected, however, if I return the $contract as JSON (e.g. in a Response), the `projects` node is empty. I've verified that the accessor is called, but the end JSON does not contain the projects.

So, `Response::json($contract)` returns a JSON object that includes `projects : {}`, but `Response::json($contract->projects)` returns the projects correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening probably because projects is not an attribute of the model and you haven't added `'projects'`to the `$appends` property of your model. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json (near the end)

UPDATE:

The problem was happening because of the method `attributesToArray` not handling instances of `ArrayableInterface`. A method override has been provided in the comments of this answer, and a relevant patch has been merged to laravel 4.1

Comment: No, that's not the case here. `projects` is an attribute, and it is included in Model's `attributesToArray` function, but when the Contract array is passed to the `json` function in `Response`, it doesn't do anything with the `Collection` of `Project`

Comment: So i looked further, this is happening because eloquent doesn't account for attributes being instances of ArrayableInterface. If you are extending all your models from a custom base model, just try putting this method in there : http://laravel.io/bin/VqdGb (you might need to put a `use Illuminate\Support\Contracts\ArrayableInterface;` on top of the file). I'll make a PR on laravel/framework.

Comment: This is putting me on the right track. The real issue is that the mutated attribute is ultimately a `Collection`. I need to somehow recursively call the toArray on Model for each level

Comment: Nope, you were right...I needed the `use` statement and it worked as expected.